# How I can use Kafka like relational database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

good time of day. I am sorry my poor English. I have some issue, can you help me to understand how i can use kafka and kafka streams like database.

My problem is i have some microservices and each service have their data in own database. I need for report purposes collect data in one point, for this i chose the kafka. I use debezuim maybe you know it (change data capture debezium), each table in relational database it is a topic in kafka. And i wrote the application with kafka stream (i joined streams each other) so far good. Example: I have the topic for ORDER and ORDER_DETAILS, after a while will come some event for join this topic, problem is i dont know when come this event maybe after minutes or after monthes or after years. How i can get data in topics ORDER and ORDER_DETAIL after month or year ? It is right way save data in topic infinitely? can you give me some advice maybe have some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The event will come as soon as there is a change in the database.

Typically, the changes to the database tables are pushed as messages to the topic.

Each and every update to the database will be a kafka message. Since there is a message for every update, you might be interested in only the latest value (update) for any given key which mostly will be the *primary key*

In this case, you can maintain the topic infinitely (`retention.ms=-1`) but compact (`cleanup.policy=compact`) it in order to save space.

You may also be interested in configuring `segment.ms` and/or `segment.bytes` for further tuning the topic retention.